# Permission denied for “dd” of Android phone's file system connected over mtpfs in Ubunutu 14.0.4

Tags: permissions, android, data-recovery, dd, mtp

I have connected my rooted Mi3 android phone to Ubuntu 14.0.4 using `jmtpfs`. I am using `~/Desktop/phone` as my mount point. I am able to browse the Android device using `Nautilus`.

Now I want to recover the files from my phone because I have done a factory reset. I am using the dd command to make a clone of the storage of the phone. When I try to do this I get the following error:

```
:~/Desktop$ sudo sh -c "dd if=~/Desktop/phone of=/media/sf_phone_recovery/image"
dd: failed to open ‘~/Desktop/phone’: Permission denied
```

Is it because the phone has root priviliges?

```
:~/Desktop/phone$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root 0 May 19 4441318 Internal storage
```

I have also tried Foremost to recover files but it takes forever to run. Have important files on my phone. Help needed asap.

This is the output of `lsblk`:

```
:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  14.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   8.3G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   5.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I am running Ubuntu using VirtualBox on Mac OSX Yosemite.

**EDIT:**
This question has been answered at the android.stackexchange.com [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116275/permission-denied-for-dd-of-android-phones-file-system-connected-over-mtpfs-i).

I am marking the answer given by @solsTiCe as the correct answer because it contains important information about MTP protocol and dd command. It also offers an alternative of using the Android terminal to dd the system image on the SD card/ pen drive (connected to your phone via a USB OTG cable). Haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Add the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 android device does not show up in `lsblk`. Although it does show up in `mount` as    * * jmtpfs on /home/user424/Desktop/phone type fuse.jmtpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=user424)* *

Comment: Which device are you using? Is it rooted? Is the bootloader unlocked?

Comment: I am using Xiaomi Mi3 phone. Yes my phone is rooted. Root Checker App shows that Root Access is properly installed on my device. I don't think that bootloader needs to be unlocked on Mi3. Maybe it does, but my phone is definitely rooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `dd` only from a device or a file not from a directory.

Also this will likely fail because you use *MTP*. MTP is a layer above the filesystem that expose only files. It's a protocol not a true filesystem.

But even with a filesystem this will not work. You need to do that on the device. The general example is

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mydevice of=mydump.bin
```

This will not work here

If you could mount it using MSC aka. USB Mass Storage, then you should be able to do it.

**Edit**:
One other way to do it is by installing a [terminal app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) on android (with busybox ?) and do the `dd` inside that terminal. you dump it on your sd card.

Look at output of `mount` and look for your device. Here I dump the /system directory to SD card.

```
mount
[...]
/emmc@android /system ....
[...]
su -
dd if=/emmc@android of=/storage/sdcard1/mydump.bin
```

Comment: Is it dd=if or dd if=? Also is mydump.bin being saved on the Android device. If it is won't it overwrite the same data that I am trying to recover?

Comment: This was an general example. I corrected it

Comment: Mi3 has Android 4.4.4. which does not support USB Mass Storage. As for dd ing it using an Android terminal, Mi3 does not have an SD card. Even if it had I would want to recover the files from that as well.

Comment: You better ask in https://android.stackexchange.com/